# Allow CUDA development in VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, cuda

I would like to do CUDA development in a Ubuntu 16.04 Virtualbox guest. It is not necessary to actually run the built application, it just needs to compile.

I installed cuda-9-2 using the command `sudo apt install cuda-9-2`, this however also installs the `nvidia-396` driver, a dependency from CUDA 9.2. After reboot, it is in a never-ending loop trying to start the display manager using the installed nvidia driver, which of course fails since there is no actual NVIDIA hardware available. The display manager won't start until CUDA and NVIDIA drivers are removed again.

Is there any way to disable the NVIDIA drivers while keeping the CUDA toolkit installed and allowing me to compile CUDA code?

Answer (score 0):

This solution was provided on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306724/ubuntu-14-04-how-to-install-cuda-6-5-without-installing-nvidia-driver

Alternatively, Robert Crovella provided the following on stackoverflow:

> If you use a deb (package manager) install method provided by NVIDIA
>   you can just install cuda-toolkit-8-0 instead of install cuda to get
>   the toolkit install without the drivers. This information is covered
>   in the CUDA linux install guide and in numerous topics on the web.

Using the cuda*.run method worked for me but the default install directory required setting an environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH appropriately to get the Qt build process to recognize the cuda toolkit. It is possible that using the .deb method with `install cuda-toolkit-8-0` would have been easier, as it seems to take care of those details for you.